# Matrices and precalculus

Tags: matrices

Let $\mathbf {A}$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix. For every two-dimensional vector $\mathbf {v}$, there exists a two-dimensional vector $\mathbf{w}$ such that
$$\mathbf {A} \mathbf {w} = \mathbf {v}$$
Show that $\mathbf {A}$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
You can use the property simultaneously:
$$
A (w_1, w_2) = (v_1, v_2)
$$
What are these combined objects?

What would be a useful choice for the RHS object? (It can give you the desired object on the LHS)

Answer (score 0):

$Aw$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$. So this implies any two dimensional vector $v$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the columns of $A$. Thus the dimension of he column space of $A$ is $2$, that is it has full column rank, hence it is invertible.

Also you can think of it in this way. There exists $w_1$ and $w_2$ such that $$Aw_1=\binom{1}{0}~~~~\text{and}~~~~Aw_2=\binom{0}{1}$$. Then $A[w_1~w_2]=I$ where I is the identity matrix of dimension $2$. Then $A^{-1}=[w_1~w_2]$